# Java JComboBox inner dotted border after select

Tags: java, swing

[image]

I want to remove that inner dotted border after select something from ComboBox.

I tried

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.focus", new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

but not working. How can remove that border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you give this one a  try ? I hope it helps

```
combobox.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

if you want to remove focus (i think dotted border you mention can be result of focus on widget) you can use
`getNextFocusableComponent() and requestFocusInWindow()`

Comment: It not work. Dotted Border still appear. It seems to change something like padding. Dotted Border is moved little bit to left and up. P.S.: boxOrientation.setFocusable(false); - work. Thanks for taking your time for helping me.