# Remove focus from JComboBox Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, combobox, focus

I am trying to remove the dotted line from my `JComboBox`.
The initial ComboBox [Initial JComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxj0g.png) has a dotted line after it has gained focus:
[After clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQZLd.png)

Now, I want to remove that focus. However I can't find it in the `UIManager`'s options (https://gist.github.com/itzg/5938035). I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153530/java-jcombobox-inner-dotted-border-after-select) post from May 2018, but the answer is not there yet.

I have tried the following:

```
  jComboBox.setFocusable(false);
  UIManager.put("ComboBox.focus", new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

but none of them worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
comboBox.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI());
```

This will result in the following after an element was selected and get you rid of the dotted border:

[image]

For removing any 'kind' of focus border, you need to override the `ComboBoxUI` which is used for drawing the box and its component.

Here is the code I used to achieve the example:

```
public ComboboxWithoutDottedBorder() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(Exception ignored){}
       this.setVisible(true);
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
       JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>();
       this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       combo.addItem("A");
       combo.addItem("B");
       combo.addItem("C");
       combo.addItem("D");
       combo.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI());

       this.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       this.add(combo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know of any other way of achieving this? I would like to keep the Windows LAF for the comboBox if possible.

Comment: As I stated you can write an own class that extends ComboBoxUI and implement your own behaviour. There is no out-of-the-box solution for this. Please do not use any methods that remove the focus from your element, because users should be able to navigate by keyboard;)